# Why is my Entity Framework Migration referring to tables that don't exist?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I cant figure out why my migration code is being created incorrectly.
There have been no changes to the database model since I created the database.

Yet if I try creating a migration it fills with code that does not refer to the correct structure..
For example in the Up method I get

```
 DropForeignKey("dbo.Accounts", "BillingAddress_Id", "dbo.Addresses");
```

when in fact there are no accounts or addresses tables.

I am creating the migration in package manager using add-migration myname -StartUpProjectName UI
I have the DataLayer as the default project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explicitly naming the -project and the -Startupproject parameters seemed to help fix this.
i.e

```
add-migration kfirst -project DataLayer -StartUpProjectName UI
```